# Screen rebuilds itself every time I try to enter some text to TextField if I use ConnectionState.waiting

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'd like to build a profile screen with real-time changes using firestore.
Whenever the profile screen opens, I get this error for a very short moment:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#f10b3], _InheritedTheme], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#47356):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> file:///C:/Users/batuh/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_appp/lib/screens/profile.dart:40:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _ProfileState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_appp/screens/profile.dart:107:42)
#1      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:545:81)
#2      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
```

But after that moment, it gets the data and works well. I know I need to use the code below to prevent that, just like to Flutter docs say.

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
```

But whenever I use that code, every time I press on a TextField, the profile page rebuilds itself and so it doesn't allow me to enter any text. If the code above is not used, everything works well, I am able to enter some text to TextFields, and the user data is being updated. I don't know what to do. Am I using the stream builder incorrectly? What should I do?

Here's the scaffold of the stful widget in my profile.dart file:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowLeft),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    ),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.cog),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settings'),
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: users.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("Something went wrong");
      }

      return Container(...);
```

**Fixed version:**

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Something went wrong");
          } else if(snapshot.hasData || snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            return Container(...);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try remove the "!" on the "data" because every time you trigger that "TextField" it will instantly looking for data. "!" in null-safety means it cannot be null object or null thing. Try remove that first because I guess your Stream builder act as a Search Recommendation

Comment: I tried that just now but then dart wants me to add a null check there again. Do I need to add a '?' to somewhere else to remove that '!'?

Comment: Yes, Put the "?" because "?" represents the data can be null and it's ok that the object is null. When you put the "!", it does not accept null value and it will immediately throw an error. If you put the "?", the system will act more relief because it know that the value can be null

Comment: It's not working, too. I added '?' to both data but still rebuilds immediately after I press on the TextFields or gives the null error if I don't use the ConnectionState.waiting check.

Comment: If that is the case, then switch back the original code and then try put if-else statement to handle the null

Comment: Okay, everything is fixed now. I am able to use the ConnectionState check as well. Big thanks to you!

Comment: And also thank you for the info about the difference between '!' and '?', too.

Comment: A big congratulations to you sir

Answer (score 0):

Where do you define your TextEditingController? If it's in a StatelessWidget, try converting it to a StatefulWidget. Whenever you refresh the state of a StatlessWidget, it will re-instantiate its fields (in your case, your TextEditingController ...). That behaviour is not true for a StatefulWidget since the state is preserved.

Comment: I am using a StatefulWidget and created the TextEditingController inside of the State. I added the '?' and made the snapshot data nullable instead of checking if it's null with '!'. And it is working now. Thanks anyway.